# Query not displaying the records

Tags: php, mysql

Hope you can help. I am running a query but no results are showing and I this is just when I try to link 2 of the result field with one another please help?

here is my code

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/overall/header.php';
?>
<div class="article">
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ref_employees");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
if(($user_data['user_id']) == 'employerid'){
  {


    echo '<h4>  ID                  :  '.$row['idnumber'] ;
    echo '<br>  First Name          :  '.$row['firstname'];
    echo '<br>  Last Name           :  '.$row['lastname'];
    echo '<br>  Reference 1       :  '.$row['ref1'];
    echo '<br>  Reference 2    :  '.$row['ref2'];
     echo '<br>  Reference 3    :  '.$row['ref3'];
      echo '<br>  Gender    :  '.$row['gender'];
      echo '<br>  EMP ID    :  '.$row['employerid'];
      echo '<br>  employed     :  '.$row['employed'];
    echo ' </h4>';
  include 'includes/adminmenu.php';

   } 
}


mysqli_close($con);?>
</div>

<?php include 'includes/overall/footer.php';

?>
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I need it to display only if the employerid(TableB) == the user_id(TableA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line:

```
if(($user_data['user_id']) == 'employerid'){
```

should be:

```
if(($user_data['user_id']) == $row['employerid']){
```

But you might save some resources and code by querying for the exact ID if that is all you need.

```
SELECT * FROM ref_employees WHERE employerid={$user_data['user_id']}
```

You have also misplaces a { in your while() loop.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
if(($user_data['user_id']) == 'employerid'){
  {
```

Should be:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  if(($user_data['user_id']) == 'employerid'){
```

Comment: Its still not displaying any records

Comment: You will have to give more detail. Are $con and $user_data['user_id'] actually set? If you take out the if() condition, do you see any resultys? Can you run the query from the command line and get results?

Comment: Check the edit, looks like you had a { in the wrong place as well.